# Composer: cannot remove dependency on production

Tags: composer-php

On a local symfony project I removed an unused dependency with `composer remove logger`, which worked without any problem. When I tried to remove it from production I mess up my project and get the following error:

> Package "symfony/monolog-bundle" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring. Loading composer repositories with
>   package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Nothing to install or update Package symfony/lts is abandoned, you
>   should avoid using it. Use symfony/flex instead. Generating autoload
>   files ocramius/package-versions:  Generating version class...
>   ocramius/package-versions: ...done generating version class Executing
>   script cache:clear [KO]  [KO] Script cache:clear returned with error
>   code 255 !!   !!   [WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:
>   !!   !!  In srcProdProjectContainer.php line 938: !!
>   !!    Class 'Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger' not found   !!
>   !!   !!   !!   [WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:
>   !!   !!  In srcProdProjectContainer.php line 938: !!
>   !!    Class 'Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger' not found   !!
>   !!   !!   !!  In srcProdProjectContainer.php line 922: !!
>   !!    Attempted to load class "Logger" from namespace
>   "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog".     !!    Did you forget a "use" statement
>   for e.g. "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log   !!    \Logger" or
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Tests\Logger"?                      !!
>   !!   !!  cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help]
>   [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi]
>   [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]  !!
>   !!
>
> Removal failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

So it seems it is not even installed? I run `composer require logger` and it installs, after I again run `composer remove logger` and I get another error about the lock file being not in sync. I removed the lock file and run composer install, which works. I then try `composer remove logger` once more and get the error:

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Package operations: 0 installs, 0
>   updates, 3 removals
>     - Removing symfony/monolog-bundle (v3.3.1)
>     - Removing symfony/monolog-bridge (v4.1.7)
>     - Removing monolog/monolog (1.24.0) Package symfony/lts is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/flex instead.
>   Writing lock file Generating autoload files ocramius/package-versions:
>   Generating version class... ocramius/package-versions: ...done
>   generating version class Symfony operations: 1 recipe
>   (b1d72bd33ffcb308097230cfdbc2a279)
>     - Unconfiguring symfony/monolog-bundle (>=3.1): From github.com/symfony/recipes:master Executing script cache:clear [KO] 
>   [KO] Script cache:clear returned with error code 255 !!   !!
>   [WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:
>   !!   !!  In srcProdProjectContainer.php line 939: !!
>   !!    Class 'Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger' not found   !!
>   !!   !!   !!   [WARNING] Some commands could not be registered:
>   !!   !!  In srcProdProjectContainer.php line 939: !!
>   !!    Class 'Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger' not found   !!
>   !!   !!   !!  In srcProdProjectContainer.php line 923: !!
>   !!    Attempted to load class "Logger" from namespace
>   "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog".     !!    Did you forget a "use" statement
>   for e.g. "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log   !!    \Logger" or
>   "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Tests\Logger"?                      !!
>   !!   !!  cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help]
>   [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi]
>   [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]  !!
>   !!
>
> Removal failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

I don't understand why this just won't work and it is really confusing. Does anyone understand what I do wrong or what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be a cache problem. Although I had tried to clear the cache before with `php bin/console cache:clear` this was not enough.

In the folder `/var/cache/prod` there is a file `srcProdProjectContainer.php` which I had to delete. After deleting this file I managed to remove the dependency.